# Modify values of array / multidimensional array

Tags: php

Currently I want transform dates stored in mysql (dateime) to FR format, here is my current function :

```
public static function convert_dates($result){
    foreach ($result as $key => $value){
            if (count($result) != count($result, COUNT_RECURSIVE)){
                 foreach ($result[$key] as $key2 => $value2){
                    if(preg_match('#date#', $key2) && !empty($value2) && $value2!='0000-00-00'){
                        if (preg_match("#^\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}$#", $value2)) {
                                $result[$key][$key2] = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($value2));
                        }elseif (preg_match("#^\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}:\d{2}$#", $value2)) {
                                $result[$key][$key2] = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($value2));
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }else{
                if(preg_match('#date#', $key) && !empty($value) && $value!='0000-00-00'){
                    if (preg_match("#^\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}$#", $value)) {
                            $result[$key] = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($value));
                    }elseif (preg_match("#^\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}:\d{2}$#", $value)) {
                            $result[$key] = date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($value));
                    }
                }
            }

    }
    return $result;
}
```

I call this function when I fetch array results from query, it can be single item or many items.

Actually it works, but there is any way to improve the code?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can most certainly be improved. In a couple of ways. The fist is that you've duplicated the code for actually transforming the dates. The logic is the same, you're just trying to map recursively. The second is that you shouldn't use `if (count($result) != count($result, COUNT_RECURSIVE))` to check if it's an array, you should use `if (is_array($result))`. Thirdly, though this seems less important, you should probably store your dates as `DateTime` objects, not as strings. But we'll ignore this for now, you can improve this later. So an improved version of the code would be

```
function transformDate($value) {
    if (preg_match("#^\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2}$#", $value)) {
        return date("d/m/Y", strtotime($value));
    } elseif (preg_match("#^\d{4}\-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}\:\d{2}:\d{2}$#", $value)) {
        return date("d/m/Y H:i:s", strtotime($value));
    }

    return $value;
}

public static function convert_dates($result) {
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            //Have this function call itself reccursively
            $result[$key] = self::convert_dates($value);
        } else if (preg_match('#date#', $key) && !empty($value) && $value!='0000-00-00') {
            $result[$key] = transformDate($value);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I would suggest using the `array_map` function instead of actually modifying the array directly, but it's support for keys doesn't looks like its well documented. This should handle more than two dimensional arrays, as it should traverse down `n` dimensions